# remote booting into guest os

Tags: virtualization, kvm-virtualization, remote, guest-os

I have installed kvm. and i installed  Ubuntu  as guest OS in kvm. Now I want to centralize the system. where my users will log in to to their guest account remotely. if yes how to do this?

Comment: Do you mean users should be able to log into the system over the network, or do you mean users should have their own VM that they can boot and log into?

Comment: Oh well, this is a very complex task indeed. Read the How-To's about XDMCP, LTS (Linux Terminal Server), PXE-Boot / TFTP and so on.
With some knowledge, you could build a Remote Desktop Server or provide ThinClients OSes over the network (PXE Boot), but there would be much to do for you.
A free Client and commercial Server would be 2X ThinClient OS.
http://distrowatch.com/?newsid=07287

Comment: users should be able to log into the system over the network

Comment: As i mentioned in my answer, you could try the Linux Terminal Server project. You'll surely have success with it when using linux based clients. If your clients are Windows, there would be more to do.
So i hope you'll have success and accept my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setup a linux terminal server on your kvm machine (see http://www.ltsp.org/ on how to do it). Then create users on the machine and let your clients connect over your local network to your virtual terminal server.
If you want to connect remotely from your clients to the server (e.g. corporate remote network, VPN) you'll have to forward the appropiate network ports to your kvm machine. This would be done on the router.

Answer (score 0):

If your users are on the same network they can login into the kvm virtual machines, because machines are visible on local network.

If it's outside of the network, they should have an access to a local network first, for example through a VPN service etc.

Above are examples where your KVM machines don't have a public IP's. For public IP's it's self explanatory.

Hope this helps.

Comment: How to access a KVM machine over the network and login (just out of curiousity)?

Comment: You can ssh to a machine. You can use remote desktop software. There are number of solutions you can use.

Comment: by default my user have no os in his system. he wants to boot from his home. that is to guest os.